# Necessary to include all attributes in view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In a new action in a rails I have this:

```
@client_order = ClientOrder.where(:client_id => @client.id, :order_date => 
  params[:order_date] || Date.today).first_or_initialize
```

This works perfectly and initializes a @client_order with in that @client_order a filled in client_id

Now I have noticed that in the view I'm obligated to include this line (simple_forms)

```
<%= f.hidden_field :client_id %>
```

In order to retrieve that filled in attribute in the create action.  Is this normal?  What will happen when the user changes that field (through debugging the form)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'll get the client ID given in the request.

It's normal if that's how the client is retrieved.

"Authorization" is the part of authentication/authorization that controls whether or not a user has access to a given resource; things like [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) address this.

Answer (score 0):

What does your model for `ClientOrder` and `Client` look like? It may be an association problem.

`ClientOrder`

```
belongs_to :client
```

`Client`

```
has_many :client_orders
```